# Report not showing all the Account records even when logged in as System Administrator

Tags: reporting, profile, roles

I have created a report which is an exact copy of a report created by another user with a different profile to display Account with Contacts.

I logged in as a system administrator and tried to run the report that I have created but it displays only a few records missing 4000+ records.

What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the filters, it's pretty hard to nail it down to a single answer.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox , I have added the filters screenshot. The same filters yield all the 4023 Account records for another user with a different profile. But, I logged in as system administrator still the report showing only 13 records.

Comment: I can think of 2 things.  is it restricted because of OWD? and can you double check the profile if its really system admin?

Comment: @RedDevil i have double checked and it is only sys admin profile. Will OWD plays a role even for sys admin?

Comment: Try removing each filter to see if the results expand as you expect. I would start with the bottom one.  Is the filter logic sound?

Comment: this sounds familiar to an issue I had - see my [blog entry](http://cropredysfdc.com/2016/04/14/historical-opportunity-trend-reporting-missing-opportunities/) - sysad role placement